# How to get all headers & cookies with Go/WASM

Tags: http, go, cookies, webassembly, response-headers

I am trying to send request from Go/wasm with Go's `net/http` package (I am not sure if I should use javascript's fetch function from wasm) . I cannot reach all of the response Headers and Cookies from Go/WASM even though I can see properly all of the headers and cookies on the browser (on network tab of browser  and also i can see all of the headers with curl request) . When I try to print all of the headers i can only see 2 headers on the console.Those are "Content-Length" and "Content-Type" . Does anybody knows what is the reason of this ?

Here is example code of server side:

```
import "github.com/gorilla/sessions"

var store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("super-secret-key-4"))

func (a *App) TestHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    cookieSession, _ := store.Get(r, "session")
    cookieSession.Values["test"] = "test"
    cookieSession.Save(r, w)
    w.Header().Set("Test", "test")
    io.WriteString(w, `{"test":"test"}`)
    return
}
```

Client Side:

```
func TestRequest(userName string) {

    type Payload struct {
        Name string `json:"name"`
    }
    payload := Payload{
        Name: userName,
    }
    payloadBytes, _ := json.Marshal(payload)
    body := bytes.NewReader(payloadBytes)
    req, _:= http.NewRequest("POST","localhost:8080/Test", body)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    resp, _:= http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    //a, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    //bodyString := string(a)

    for name, values := range resp.Header {
        for _, value := range values {
            log.Println(name, value)
        }
    }
    for _, cookie := range resp.Cookies() {
      log.Println(cookie.Name)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
}
```

This is what i get on the browser console:

```
wasm_exec.js:51 2021/08/04 21:08:48 Content-Length 274
wasm_exec.js:51 2021/08/04 21:08:48 Content-Type text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally see that i need to add a special header to response for use my custom headers on client side.If i add this line to my middleware i can see my custom headers on client side.

> w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers",
> "MyHeader,Myheader2")